# select non zero columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a scenario where I need to display only non zero columns

```
id C1 C2 C3 C4
 1  0  1  0  2
 2  0  1  0  5
 3  0  9  0  3
```

i want the output as below

```
id C2 C4
1   1  2
2   1  5
3   9  3
```

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: Please try the second answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521819/select-only-columns-with-null-empty-values-from-the-table

Comment: I don't want to display the Columns at all which are zeros

Answer (score 1):

An SQL query always results in before-known columns. So you cannot do what you want to do in pure SQL. (And not being able to do something with SQL only is often a sign of a poor database design. Sometimes however it's that SQL is about how to get data, not how to display it.)

What you can do is get the columns' sums in one query, then build a new query dynamically (manually or within an app with Java, PHP or whatever programming language is used) that only selects the non-zero columns.