# Select column that have value

Tags: php, mysql

```
ID | aa_view | aa_sum | bb_view | bb_sum | cc_view | cc_sum | dd_view | dd_sum |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4  |    0    |    0   |   SF    |    47  |   SF    |   43   |    0    |   0    |
```

How can I make a query that will only return column `xx_sum` if `xx_view` have value 'SF'. (value SF not fixed to any column, but if `xx_view` have 'SF' `xx_sum` will have value greater than 0)

I try to used `SELECT IF` method but I guess it just the same as normal query. I mean it just show all the field with their value.

Comment: `SELECT xx_sum WHERE xx_view LIKE 'SF'`

Comment: possible duplicate, please, read select non zero columns in mysql
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28297205/select-non-zero-columns-in-mysql

Comment: @Allkin thanks for responding. but xx represet the different between column name

Comment: Edit your question with your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

One method is a giant case statement:

```
select (case when aa_view = 'SF' then aa_sum
             when bb_view = 'SF' then bb_sum
        . . .
        end)
```

Normally, a lot of pairs of columns like this suggests a poor data structure.  You should probably have another table with columns for `id`, `type`, `view`, and `sum`.

Another approach that results in shorter code uses the MySQL functions `elt()` and `field()`:

```
select elt(field('SF', aa_view, bb_view, . . .),
           aa_sum, bb_sum, . . . )
```

Comment: doesn't work using the case statement, it just return 1 field

Comment: @KhairilAzizeeAyub . . . Your question unclear.  Because the English only contains singular words, it seemed like you only want one value.

Comment: sorry sir for my bad english.

Comment: @KhairilAzizeeAyub . . . That is just one of the reasons why sample data and desired results make questions much clearer to understand.